# Is it viable to grind above Normal for Torment now?

Tags: diablo-iii

As I understand, before the recent patch, there was no point in doing any difficulty level other than normal to gear up for torment. The drop ammount of bloodshards and legendaries was the same in normal as in master. So basically, you grinded normal until you could handle torment efficiently and jumped straight to it.

Is it the same nowadays? My barb can't really handle torment yet. Should I just grind normal or is it better to play the highest difficulty she can handle?

Comment: There is a big gap (8x) between Normal and Torment, and there is no reason to give up free Gold and XP. Generally, once you begin to almost one-shot monsters, bring it up a notch, and you will gain more Gold/XP while still two-shotting stuff. Even if you absolutely want to keep one-shotting monsters, there's no point in running Normal when you are dealing 3x of required damage, pick Expert then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably just grind normal.

Consider the D3 Difficulty chart (click for full size):

[image: D3 Difficulty Chart]

Also at the bottom of [this page](http://www.diablowiki.net/Difficulty)

Since gear on your Barb at end game should be legendaries, and you don't get legendary bonus drop chance until Torment 1, your best bet is generally to clear Normal quickly until you can handle Torment 1. Actually, if you look even closer, the only bonuses you get from Normal up to Master are:

1. Bonus XP
2. Bonus Gold Find
3. Bonus Death's Breath and Legendary Crafting Mats
4. Master Gives Imperial Gems on occasion
5. Expert and above give double bounty blood shards

With this in mind, I would never run Hard. If you are interested in getting Blood Shards from Bounties, then Expert or Master might be worthwhile - as long as it doesn't take you twice as long to finish a run. The rest of the bonuses are nice, but generally not worth it until you get to Torment 1.

Comment: fyi that's an old chart.  At the very least the legendary crafting mat drop rate has been tuned to match the DB drop rate.

Comment: @z' Thanks for mentioning. I have updated the chart, though the results are the same

Comment: More obsolete info: rift legendary bonus is +100% ([source](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12471197317)), multiplicative with Torment bonus up to +262% on T6.

Comment: Useful relative figures: monsters gain +60% HP per each difficulty step (except +100% on Normal->Hard) and +45% damage each step (except +30% on Normal->Hard).